# Looking for a phrase similar to "outlive" but in alcohol drinking context

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

I'm wondering if there is a phrase that has similar meaning with "outlive" but in alcohol drinking context.

Example sentence:

"I have a very high alcohol tolerance, I will **[phrase]** you all". Meaning, "You all will get drunk before I do".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[outdrink](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+%22%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#q=define+%22outdrink%22&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial): drink more alcohol than (another person)

[outlast](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/outlast): to endure or last longer than.

[drink you under the table](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/drink+under+the+table): to be able to drink more alcohol than someone else.

I will be the last one standing

> Young graduate dies in 'last man standing' drinking competition

[I have a hollow leg](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hollow+leg): an ability or inclination to drink large quantities of alcoholic beverages, especially without evident drunkenness.

Comment: 'Drink you under the table' is the expression I'd usually use.

Answer (score 4):

The word *[outdrink](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/outdrink)* matches your description perfectly:

> To outdo in drinking, drink more than.

It seems to have first appeared in the 1500s, per the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/133567?redirectedFrom=outdrink#eid):

> a1500  (1450)    tr. Secreta Secret. (Ashm. 396) (1977) 39 (MED),
>   Whan thou art in that pleasaunce, absteyne the fro drynke and suffre
>   others to spare it not, and lett hem drynke atavnt and outdrynke
>   other.
>
> 1622   T. Dekker & P. Massinger Virgin Martir ii. sig. D,   I durst
>   out-drinke a Lord.
>
> 1675   Mistaken Husband iii. 34   How will I gnaw the sweet-meats in
>   my fury! Out eat a Justice, and out drink a Jury.
>
> 1735   Pope Satires of Donne ii, in Wks. II. 37   Who..Out-cant old
>   Esdras, or out-drink his Heir.
>
> 1822   C. M. Sedgwick New-Eng. Tale xiii. 216   Rivington was a fit
>   companion for his new friend; addicted to a score of vices; gambling
>   high, and out-drinking, out-swearing, and out-bullying his comrades.
>
> 1891   Missionary Herald (Boston) Dec. 538   He..tried to outdrink the
>   heaviest drinkers. 1976   J. Wainwright Bastard i. 20   He couldn't
>   out-fight me. He couldn't out-daredevil me. He couldn't out-drink me.
>
> 1995   E. Toman Dancing in Limbo v. 120   There was no man in Derry he
>   couldn't outdrink.

If you're in a bar with a group of scientists, consider:

> You have a half-life of a lithium-5, you lightweight...I will **outdo** you all with my molybdenum-100!

Comment: a bit curious here.. why does it have to be a group of scientists?

Comment: @Petra Barus Purely hypothetical example :)